# Change battery from MacBook Pro to white MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Is it possible put the battery from the MacBook Pro 13″ (2009-2012) to the white MacBook (2009)?

Are they same or not and which gives me more battery life?

Answer (score 1):

The batteries are not the same.

Comment: on the photo looks same. what diference betwean this two batteries